# Which is a good way to capture request sent by a click action?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am currently working in an end to end automated test for one of our application and it would be good to validate the request sent when a button is clicked. Also validate the response for a particular request.
I am trying to find out which option I have.
The project has been build with NightwatchJS.

Comment: You would like to analyze the payload before it's sent ?

Comment: It would help. However currently is more important to validate the response.

Comment: You could create a kind of interceptor (like in `axios`), basically a function that would run each time a response is received. For instance, instead of having `fetch(/url').then(res=>...)`, you could have `const client = url => fetch('/url').then(validate).then(res => ... ` (where `validate` is a function) and use that `client` variable throughout your project